# Jenkins with Docker plugin not pulling Docker images from private registry

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, docker-registry

We have a Jenkins setup with the Docker plugin installed and want to run our build jobs in Docker Containers based on private images.

Here is what we have:

- Jenkins master runs on "bare metal" VM, no containerization
- We have a second VM with a Docker Engine running on it, the Docker engine port from this VM is exposed and accessible from the Jenkins master via TCP
- We created several Docker Templates (in the global Jenkins settings) and can use them in our build jobs, as long as we use the "never pull" strategy for the images

The problems occurs when we try to pull an image from our private registry (we use Artifactory for this and it is accessible from the Docker Engine, since we can successfully push images from our Docker VM).

Whenever we start a job in Jenkins that uses such an image which should always be pulled from the private registry, we see `All nodes of label ‘OUR_IMAGE_LABEL’ are offline` and the job is hanging forever.

The strange thing is that we don't see anything related to such a job in the Jenkins log (`/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log` on the Jenkins master) nor do we see anything in the Docker logs (`/var/log/messages` on the VM with the Docker Engine).

Things work perfectly fine, if we switch back to the "Never pull" strategy and have the image locally available on the Docker engine.

Any ideas

- why things are not working
- how we could get at least some log messages regarding what Jenkins is doing, when it shows `All nodes of label ‘OUR_IMAGE_LABEL’ are offline`

Comment: just as a reminder to myself: seems like we did not use the proper private registry prefix to make Docker pull the image from our private registry - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39741501/docker-pull-push-using-private-registry-without-prefixing